# How to console.log inside subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscribe

I have a node server with mongoose connection.
I have a angular frontend that has a service which uses subscribe.

```
this.http.post(`${this.uri}/update/${id}`, obj).subscribe(
  res => this.router.navigate(['test'])
);
```

And here is the problem, because i dont understand the syntax for that.
I want to console.log something after the res => this.router.navigate(['test']).
I tried:

```
this.http.post(`${this.uri}/update/${id}`, obj).subscribe(
  res => this.router.navigate(['test']),
  () => console.log('test')
);
```

But the () part is never called. How can I console log something after the router function call?
Also when I rename res, everything still works. What exactly is the res variable? I have to admit I copied the .subscribe part from another answer here.

Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to console.log something after the res =>
>   this.router.navigate(['test'])

Change

```
this.http.post(`${this.uri}/update/${id}`, obj).subscribe(
  res => this.router.navigate(['test']),
  () => console.log('test')
);
```

to

```
this.http.post(`${this.uri}/update/${id}`, obj).subscribe(
  res => {
      this.router.navigate(['test']);
      console.log('test');
  }
);
```

> What exactly is the res variable?

Its the response that you get from the server as a result of http request.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. I can name res however I want right?

Comment: Yes, whatever you want